# Android - Webservice, php vs. ASP.NET, XML vs. JSON?

Tags: php, android, asp.net, xml, json

I am in the process of developing my first Android app and I need to send/receive data from a remote MSSQL database. I am pretty comfortable with both php and asp.net so which one is the most efficient for interacting with android via webservice? and then what is the best/fastest means of communication, xml or json?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Many thanks for the responses. I had originally intended to use an xml based service only because I have worked with it more than JSON. However after a bit of research and your responses, I think I will pursue the JSON route. As far as the platform, I am still undecided... Maybe I will create a test in both for kicks and giggles :) Thanks again for your input!

Comment: good luck.. let us know what you end up using

Answer (score 0):

JSON should be faster with the same data structures as the payload will be smaller than the XML representation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rick that JSON generally results in smaller messages to and from the server which is a good thing for mobile platforms.

In terms of which platform to use server side, it's really a bit a loaded one.  Both PHP and ASP.net make creating either a SOAP Web Service or a RESTful service quite easy.  I would say it comes down to which platform you are most comfortable with.

We currently use ASP.NET MVC to host a few really simple resources which return JSON results from HTTP GET requests, we then consume the response in our andriod app.  I started off using Python and the GAE before moving off the GAE and using a dedicated server I liked this choice becuase the linux boxes are generally a little cheaper than the windows boxes.  In the end I found that my knowledge of ASP.NET being considerably more than my knowledge of python, along with the fact I didn't see too much point in becoming an expert in python, that moving to ASP.NET made sense.

Since the server stack is now ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008 I haven't looked at it for 2 years it just keeps plugging along and I couldn't be happier.

So ultimately, if its a project for just yourself, chose which ever you are most comfortable with.

Hope this helps